# How can I match custom PropertyGrid BrowsableAttributes entries?

Tags: c#

I have a class(KeywordProperties) with this code :

```
public class KeywordProperties
    {
        [DisplayMode("0-1,0-2,0-3,1-1,1-2,1-3,1-6,1-9,1-10,1-11,1-12,2-1,2-2,2-3,2-9,2-10,2-12,3-1,3-2,3-3,3-10,3-12,4-13,5,6")]
        public string Onvaan { get; set; }

        [DisplayMode("0-1,0-2,0-3,1-1,1-2,1-3,1-6,1-9,1-10,1-11,1-12,2-1,2-2,2-3,2-9,2-10,2-12,3-1,3-2,3-3,3-10,3-12,4-13,5,6")]
        public string MozooKolli { get; set; }

        [DisplayMode("0-10,1-10,3-10,3-12,5,6")]
        public string EsmeDars { get; set; }

        [DisplayMode("0-1,1-1,2-1,2-2,3-1,6")]       
        public string Sokhanraan { get; set; }

        [DisplayMode("0-10,1-2,2-1,2-10,3-10,6")]
        public string Modares { get; set; }
}
```

And I have another for check attributes :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class DisplayModeAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string mode;
    public DisplayModeAttribute(string mode)
    {
        this.mode = mode ?? "";
    }
    public override bool Match(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as DisplayModeAttribute;
        if (other == null) return false;

        if (other.mode == mode) return true;

        // allow for a comma-separated match, in either direction
        if (mode.IndexOf(',') >= 0)
        {
            string[] tokens = mode.Split(',');
            if (Array.IndexOf(tokens, other.mode) >= 0) return true;
        }
        else if (other.mode.IndexOf(',') >= 0)
        {
            string[] tokens = other.mode.Split(',');
            if (Array.IndexOf(tokens, mode) >= 0) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want display properties in propertygrid with this code :

```
String Code = "":
KeywordProperties Kp = new KeywordProperties();
propertygrid1.SelectedObject = Kp;
propertygrid1.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(new DisplayModeAttribute(Code));
```

When Code vlue is "0-1" or "5" or ...(single value), I can see my properties.
But, when use "0-1,1-2" for Code, I can't see any thing in my properygrid.

How can I see these data :

1- All properties that have code **0-1 and** code **1-2** :

result is :**Onvaan,MozooKolli**

2- All properties that have code **0-1 or** code **1-2** :

result is : **Onvaan,MozooKolli,Sokhanraan,Modares**

Comment: Windows application, Propertygrid is control.

Comment: What are you working on? WebApplication or WindowsApplication or WPFApplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your code only matches `DisplayModeAttributes` when both have a single value, or one contains a single value and the other contains multiple values; it won't match them when both contain multiple values, unless the list of values are identical.

To use your code as-is, you could change the way you populate *PropertyGrid.BrowsableAttributes*:

```
propertygrid1.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(
    new DisplayModeAttribute("0-1"),
    new DisplayModeAttribute("1-2")
    // etc.
);
```

Alternatively, to fix your matching code, you could replace it with something like:

```
public override bool Match(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as DisplayModeAttribute;

    if (other == null)
        return false;

    if (other.mode == mode)
        return true;

    string[] modes = mode.Split(',');
    string[] others = other.mode.Split(',');

    var matches = modes.Intersect(others);

    return matches.Count() > 0;
}
```

This uses the [LINQ Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302032.aspx) method, which returns the elements that two lists have in common.

Comment: part 1 of your answer has error : 'System.ComponentModel.AttributeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Add' !Please help me.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see that *AttributeCollection* has a constructor that takes a `params` array. I've corrected my example code.

Comment: Thank's, but how can I set string array(array of codes) in parameters list. for example : propertygrid1.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(new DisplayModeAttribute(myStringArrayCode)); that my array nclude "0-1","1-2","3-5",... Length is dynamic.

Comment: Your DisplayModeAttribute class doesn't support using an array like that. You could change the class to do so, but you would also have to change your matching code.

Alternatively, you could try something like `propertygrid1.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(myStringArrayCode.Select(s => new DisplayModeAttribute(s)).ToArray());`